# Is it possible to ensure C# virtual properties have both accessors in derived classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I see the following in the C# language spec.

> If the inherited property includes both accessors (i.e., if the inherited property is read-write), the overriding property can include either a single accessor or both accessors.

Suppose I want to ensure that if the derived class overrides the virtual property, it has both the getter and the setter. Is there a way to ensure this, without having to split the virtual property into two separate ones?

Comment: I think the only way to *ensure* that something is overridden is to make it `abstract`, not `virtual`.  Or include it in an interface.  `virtual` provides a default implementation and *allows* overriding, but doesn't require it.

Comment: Thanks David, I've tried to clarify my question that I want to ensure *if* the property is overridden, both the getter and setter are overridden.

Comment: That still doesn't change how `virtual` works, though.  Understand that the getter and the setter are two different methods on the class.  Both are independently `virtual`.  An inheriting class can override one, both, or neither.  I don't think the language itself has a mechanism to *conditionally* enforce whether overriding is required based on the overriding of something else.  You'd probably need to do some reflection in the parent class to try and see (if it even *can* see from the parent class) what's been overridden and what hasn't, and raise an exception at runtime.

Comment: It also doesn't change the fact that it's none of your business how the derived class overrides the properties. The derived classes (in general) do not belong to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

**David** is right.  I would argue that forcing your child class to override a virtual property goes against [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) Principles.  One purpose of a base class is to provide base implementations available for child classes to use.  If you're telling your children they *must* implement it, than you as a parent shouldn't be providing a base implementation (Obvious family parallel intended).

To force your child to override the member, it must be *abstract*.

In this example, the base class provides a default implementation:

```
// Base Abstract Class
public abstract class Avenger
{
    public virtual string MyVehicle
    {
        get
        {
            if (MyVehicle == null)  // Default the value if it is null
                MyVehicle = "Quinjet";  
            return MyVehicle;
        }
        set; // Allow the child class to set their own vehicle
    }
}

// Derrived class piggy-backs off of the parent's implementation
public class Hulk : Avenger
{}
```

In this example, the base class *forces* the child class to implement the member by not providing one of his own (using *abstract*)

```
// Base Abstract Class
public abstract class Avenger
{
    public abstract string MyIdentity { get; }
}

// Not implementing MyIdentity results in compile error
public class Hulk : Avenger
{ }
```

*Compile Error: 'Hulk' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Avenger.myIdentity.get'*

But to **John's** point, the parent cannot control the behavior of the child.
This compiles:

```
// Base Abstract Class
public abstract class Avenger
{
    public abstract string MyIdentity { get; }
}

// Derrived class implements abstract member
public class Hulk : Avenger
{
    public override string MyIdentity
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException("Won't tell"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'll take David's answer as I think reflection is necessary here.